# Replace string with NA in R dataframe column

Tags: r

I am having trouble finding the syntax for replacing a string value in a data frame column with NA in r language. The whole column is made up of 1s and 0s, but because of these 2 string outlier values, the whole column is registering as character rather than numeric.   I want to convert these outlier strings to NAs, and then the whole column to numeric.

Here is the output from the frequency table column

[image: Here is the output from the frequency table column]

I have downloaded the recode() tool from the package car, but I can’t make it work with the character value.

Let me know if anyone can help!

Comment: Hi! Thank you for taking the time to ask a question, but as currently written, the question is not properly tagged. If you tag questions properly you have more chances of getting help from corresponding person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a vector `x`

```
x <- c(1, 0, "45 mins", "10 mins")
x
#[1] "1"       "0"       "45 mins" "10 mins"
```

you can do

```
as.numeric(x)
#[1]  1  0 NA NA
# Warning message:
# NAs introduced by coercion
```

So try

```
dataframe$column <- as.numeric(dataframe$column)
```